# .NET Core CORS policy block

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

There are two applications on the iis server, one is react with the front end and the other is the back end. web api works as a subdomain. forexample, api.mydomain.com.

I get the following error when I send a web api request from the front end.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.mydomain.com/api/auth/login'
> from origin 'https://.mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

```
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://*.mydomain.com").AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
        });

app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");
```

Do I need to change IIS settings, where should I change?

**SOLUTION:**

1. First of all, set all the cors settings from web config to "*".
2. Second, turn off modsecurity from the plesk panel.

Comment: No one can help? i can't solve the problem

Comment: I think the problem is your web api don't know how to return 20x response for a preflight request. So you need modify your code to allow OPTION to return correct response.

Comment: @JokiesDing I found the problem, the problem was that the modsecurity in the plesk panel was turned on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting your web application on IIS you need to let IIS know about the cors Policy as well.

you have to edit your web config as explained here:

https://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html

Comment: Gave this error --> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Answer (score 0):

implemented in version 2.0.0

```
options.AddPolicy("MyCorsPolicy",
       builder => builder
          .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
          .WithOrigins("https://*.mydomain.com")
          .AllowAnyMethod()
          .AllowCredentials()
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .Build()
       );
    app.UseCors("MyCorsPolicy");
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.setisoriginallowedtoallowwildcardsubdomains?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: [_"Voodoo programming refers to the practice of getting a program to produce desired output by using guesses, trial-and-error, cookbooks, copy-pasting from online resources, or similar techniques without truly understanding the underlying problem"_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo_programming). Explain what this code does and why the OP should use this.

Comment: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Not work.